# Interface 'SessionHandlerInterface' not found в codeigniter

Tags: php, mysqli, codeigniter, хостинг

Использую codeigniter 3. На локальном сервере все работало.Но когда на хостинг залили. Вот так выходит когда в админ панель заходишь.

```
Interface 'SessionHandlerInterface' not found
```

Как исправить? Пожалуйста помогите...

Comment: Видимо очень неожиданно, но начать надо с проверки различий окружения. Ну, например, очевиднейшая причина отсутствия builtin интерфейса - у вас музейная версия PHP. Хоть SessionHandlerInterface и появился давным-давно в 5.4.0

Comment: @Мелкий Посоветуйте, как решить?

Comment: Посоветовал уже. Мне процитировать ещё раз свой комментарий? Начните со сравнения версий.

Comment: @Мелкий версия php 5.4.45

Comment: И локально и удалённо?

Comment: @Мелкий Локально все норм, Удаленно ошибка была. удалил в моделях parent::construct и заработало.

Comment: Я про версию PHP спрашивал.

Comment: @Мелкий нет тогда. Локально 7. Удаленно 5.3.3 было